# Why do fundamental physical laws involve the second derivative?

Tags: soft-question

The title says it all. This is a question that has been nagging at me for some time. Mathematically, the first derivative is not really any different from the second derivative, or the $k$-th. So I ask, what is so special about the second derivative?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34001/

Comment: conservation of momentum doesn't involve 2nd derivative but it is the fundamental law of nature. Farady's law states that 
 $\mathcal{E} = -N {{d\Phi_B} \over dt} $ this doesn't involve 2nd derivative. Rather first derivative seems more inherent to nature.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18588/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4102/2451 and links therein.