# Why does the commutativity of partial differentiation hold for Hamiltonian?

Tags: hamiltonian, differentiation, mathematics

When I was going through canonical transformation I came across some equation like 
$$\dfrac{\partial^2 H}{\partial q \partial p} = \dfrac{\partial^2 H}{\partial p \partial q}$$ where $H$ is the Hamiltonian of a system and $q$ and $p$ are the coordinate and momentum. I know that partial differentiation is commutative when the function is of class $C^2$ . However I had no reason to believe that $H$ is so.  So why does the relation hold? Can someone help me please?

Comment: AFAIK, most rigorous formulations of Hamiltonian mechanics assume the Hamiltonian to be a *smooth* function on the phase space, so a function which is not even $C^2$ would not be a suitable candidate for a Hamiltonian.

Comment: Related:  http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1324/2451 and links therein.