# Finite square well and continuity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, mathematical-physics

In solving finite square well problem, we solve the TISE inside and outside the well, and we match the wave function at the boundary, by the continuity of wave function.

Now this bugs me, since the wavefunction is only assume to be square-integrable, why we can use the continuity of wavefunction?

Edit: There is no problem for this bound state solution to hold, but will we miss other non-continuous solutions?

Comment: Could you clarify where you see a contradiction?

Comment: [Maybe related?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/218314/why-does-the-wavefunction-have-to-be-continuous-in-the-presence-of-a-dirac-delta)

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19667/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38181/2451 and links therein.